# How to get solution file error using process concepts?

Tags: c#, process

I have tried to compile a .NET .sln in C# which uses the `System.Diagnostics.Process` namespace. The solution files are compiled successfully but a file error occurs.

The following code was used:

```
Process process = new Process();
                      process.StartInfo.FileName = MsbuildLocation + "\\MSBuild.exe";
                      process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + projectPath + "\"" + " /p:Configuration=Release ;
                      Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(MsbuildLocation);
                      process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                      process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                      process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                      process.Start();

                      if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                      {
                        string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

}

I use above logic.

I facing this (**"StandardError has not been redirected."**) error.

How to solve this error and get solution file errors?

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting Standard Input instead of Standard Error.

Add or replace `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;` under `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;`